# filp/whoops: как разрешить дальнейшее выполнение скрипта?

Tags: php

Приветствую, уважаемые коллеги.

Кто работал с библиотекой обработки ошибок [filp/whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops/) (она используется, например, в Laravel 4), может быть, знает, как выполнить действие в handler'е, но продолжить рендеринг страницы? Чтобы вопрос был яснее, кратко опишу задачу.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы сайт сообщал об ошибках в удобной форме. Условно есть два типа ошибок: фатальные и нефатальные. На фатальных выводится лендинг и отсылаются алерты по почте. Нефатальные ошибки нужно сбрасывать в лог, и далее отдавать страницу в штатном режиме.

Если с первой подзадачей проблем нет, то вторая никак не дается - когда *error_reporting(E_ALL)*, Whoops глушит движок, когда *E_ERROR*, игнорирует замечания и предупреждения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После исследования исходников стало ясно, что решить вопрос можно только через наследование. Добавил методы, которые устанавливают типы ошибок для "тихого" логгирования, возможно, решение кому-нибудь пригодится:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Класс исправляет несовершенства Whoops:
 * позволяет объявить определенные ошибки нефатальными,
 * что дает скрипту возможность вполняться после обработки ошибок.
 */
class MyWhoops extends \Whoops\Run
{

protected $byPassLevel;

/**
 * In certain scenarios, like in shutdown handler, we can not throw exceptions
 * @var bool
 */
private $canThrowExceptions = true;

/**
 * Метод перегружен для того, чтобы нефатальные ошибки не глушили движок
 *
 */
public function handleError($level, $message, $file = null, $line = null)
{
    if ($level & error_reporting()) {
        foreach ($this->silencedPatterns as $entry) {
            $pathMatches = (bool) preg_match($entry["pattern"], $file);
            $levelMatches = $level & $entry["levels"];
            if ($pathMatches && $levelMatches) {
                // Ignore the error, abort handling
                return true;
            }
        }
        // XXX we pass $level for the "code" param only for BC reasons.
        // see https://github.com/filp/whoops/issues/267
        $exception = new ErrorException($message, /*code*/ $level, /*severity*/ $level, $file, $line);
        //в данном методе измненена только нижеследующая строка:
        if ($this->canThrowExceptions && !$this->isByPassLevel($level)) {
            throw $exception;
        } else {
            $this->handleException($exception);
        }
        // Do not propagate errors which were already handled by Whoops.
        return true;
    }

    // Propagate error to the next handler, allows error_get_last() to
    // work on silenced errors.
    return false;
}

/**
 * Метод устанавливает уровень пропуска
 *
 */
public function setByPassLevel($byPassLevel)
{
    $this->byPassLevel = $byPassLevel;
}

/**
 * Метод проверяет уровень пропуска
 *
 */
public function isByPassLevel($level)
{
    return ($level & $this->byPassLevel) > 0;
}

/**
 * Special case to deal with Fatal errors and the like.
 * Унаследовано для совместимости с приватным свойством canThrowExceptions
 */
public function handleShutdown()
{
    // If we reached this step, we are in shutdown handler.
    // An exception thrown in a shutdown handler will not be propagated
    // to the exception handler. Pass that information along.
    $this->canThrowExceptions = false;

    $error = error_get_last();
    if ($error && $this->isLevelFatal($error['type'])) {
        // If there was a fatal error,
        // it was not handled in handleError yet.
        $this->handleError(
            $error['type'],
            $error['message'],
            $error['file'],
            $error['line']
        );
    }
}

/**
 * Унаследовано для совместимости с приватным свойством canThrowExceptions
 */
private static function isLevelFatal($level)
{
    $errors = E_ERROR;
    $errors |= E_PARSE;
    $errors |= E_CORE_ERROR;
    $errors |= E_CORE_WARNING;
    $errors |= E_COMPILE_ERROR;
    $errors |= E_COMPILE_WARNING;
    return ($level & $errors) > 0;
}
}
```

Юзать можно вот так:

```php
<?php
$whoops = new MyWhoops;
$whoops->pushHandler(function($exception, $inspector, $run) {
if (!$run->isByPassLevel($exception->getSeverity())) {
  //выполняем код для фатальных ошибок (лэндинг, например)
  //очищаем вывод от остатков недовыполненного кода:
  return \Whoops\Handler\Handler::QUIT;
} else {
  //выполняем "на фоне" код для остальных ошибок (к примеру, логгирование)
}
})->register()->setByPassLevel(E_NOTICE|E_USER_NOTICE|E_STRICT|E_DEPRECATED|E_USER_DEPRECATED);
```